# Making the DIV close icon drag along with the DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8njzxhvx/2/)

Can't figure out how to make the DIV close icon to follow the rest of the DIV when the DIV is dragged.

I seem to think there is something in this part of the code that I am not doing right.

```
$self = $(this);
$(opts.parent).append($self);
$('span.' + opts.classPrefix + '_oClose').remove();
$('body').append($overlayClose);
$('div.' + opts.classPrefix + '_overlay').remove();
$('body').append($overlay);
$self.draggable();
```

Appears to be something to do with how elements are appended to HTML body.  I tried appending a blank div to body and then adding overlay and overlayClose to that blank div. But that did not even render the dialog. Any ideas?

Comment: You have used close icon as background image. It would be better if you use it in image tag inside your draggable div

Comment: Have you tried just adding the close overlay inside the same div as the actual overlay? It seems kind of weird that you would append it to the body?

Comment: The content that are displayed inside the div comes from someplace dynamically.  Is there a way to manipulate the dynamically filled content to add this cross icon into that?

Comment: Exactly as Scott Mitchell has posted. Check this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/8njzxhvx/3/).

Comment: @ScottMitchell, when I comment .append(@overlayClose) to the body and add $overlay.append($overlayClose).  No difference.

Comment: @ScottMitchell, thanks. It works good.  Let me check what magic you did in the code :-)

Comment: @Harry should get the thanks here...

Comment: @ScottMitchell: The original idea was yours mate. I just expanded it. I think you should add that as an answer so that OP can acknowledge it. Please feel free to use my demo in your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Harrys demo http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/8njzxhvx/3/

Line 24 has the magic :) Appending the close to the overlay then enabling the drag

```
  $self.append($overlayClose);
  $self.draggable();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your code but I think you need a parent div that would be relatively positioned and a child that is absolutely positioned.
**HTML**

```
<div id="test">Hello! Trying to figure how to make the close div icon drag along with the div. 
<img class="close" src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/status/100/close_4-512.png" alt="">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#test {
    background: lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
}

img.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

For dragging I've used **jQuery UI**:

```
$( "#test" ).draggable();

$("img.close").click( function(e){
    $("#test").fadeOut();
});
```

I've made a fiddle that explains this:
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8njzxhvx/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<div id="test">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close">Close</a>
Hello! Trying to figure how to make the close div icon drag along with the div.</div>
```

CSS:

```
.close{
 float: right;
 top: -31px;
 position: relative;
 left: 23px;
 background:url()// your close icon
```

}

This will make your anchor tag draggable along with div and you can fire event on anchor tag for closing purpose

Comment: This would work fine but I have no control on anything inside <div id="test"></div>.  ScottMichell changed a line in the code and it works good now. Thank guys.